# Is it ok to play for a team that is sponsored partially by banks and fast food restaurants?

Tags: halal-haram

Asalamualaikum,
I have a short question regarding if I could play for a high school team that gets partially sponsored by a bank and fast food restaurants knowing that I personally do not support any of the haram, and that I just would like to play. Also knowing that we pay taxes to the schools so we can have their faciliaties available to us.

Jazakallahukairan

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Muslims including sahabah are/were working for Jews knowing that they deal with riba.

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. I think it would be the same with any other place you transact with. For example when where you purchase your groceries from a non Muslim company. For example here in the USA there are many companies that deal with riba (interest). So we still purchase from them knowing our money is not being used for their riba (interest) based transactions.

So you playing on a team that has a bank based sponsor does not mean you are also involved with their riba (interest) based transactions.

**Furthermore when it comes to money from a non Muslim (in this case a donation example), from [Islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/212/accepting-donations-from-non-muslims)**

*There is nothing wrong with accepting unsolicited gifts and donations from non-Muslims, and it is permissible to spend them on Islamic projects and in other ways.



But asking for donations from non-Muslims carries several risks, such as being humiliated in front of them or being controlled by them.


If there is no danger of such things happening, there is nothing wrong with asking. When he was still in Makkah, the Prophet (peace and blessings of ALLAH be upon him) used to ask for help for the sake of da’wah, without any humiliation involved, from some of the mushrikeen, such as his uncle Abu Taalib and others. There is no humiliation involved in putting out charity boxes or circulating flyers giving account numbers for donations, and so on. And Allaah knows best.*

**Have a nice day!**